# Can anyone deal with it?

Tags: android, media-player, onhover

I would like my button (should it be a button or sth else?) to to play music when I hover on it and stop at HOVER_EXIT. What should I implement for 
    `case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE:` to make button play music still, without pauses from `ENTER` to `EXIT` and on `MOVE` dont do anything?
There is also an error - when I try to open a screen with this hoverbutton, app crashes and turns off.
Here is my java code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);
    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnHoverListener(new View.OnHoverListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onHover(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            MediaPlayer player=MediaPlayer.create(DisplayActivity.this,R.raw.sound);
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER:
                   player.start();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT:
                    player.stop();
                    break;
            }
            return true;

        }
    });}`
```

Comment: Could you please share the `logcat`?

Comment: Here is error line:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.appname/com.example.android.appname.DisplayActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView`

Comment: It looks like, somewhere in your code, you are trying to assign reference of `Button` to `ImageView`. Is the code mentioned in the question complete?

Comment: @user3161880 Now everything works correctly, but when i hover on my button, music doesnt play :(
Have you got any ideas about how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class DisplayActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // create media player only when required
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);

        // this will keep the audio playing, even if you hover for long time
        player.setLooping(true);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // release is as soon as possible
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);

        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnHoverListener(new View.OnHoverListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onHover(
                    View v,
                    MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER:
                    player.start();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT:
                    // if you choose to stop the player, you need to prepare it again by calling player.prepare(); before restarting it.
                    // I chose to pause it and seek it back to beginning
                    player.pause();
                    player.seekTo(0);
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)